# PCH File in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode6, pch

In my previous projects, I can find the `.pch` file under Supporting Files.

But now in Xcode 6, I couldn't find any `.pch` file. Any steps should I do to produce this file?

Comment: Shame that you've not got an answer to this yet, I've just run across the same issue. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Add the pch file which is under Others in File-New...and don't forget to add it to your LLVM6.0 - Language section of Build Settings as Project/whateveryounamedyourpchfile.pch

Answer (score 433):

1. Make new file: <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
2. iOS/Mac > Other > PCH File > YourProject-Prefix.pch.
3. Make sure you display "All" and not "Basic". (Blue buttons)
4. Project > Build Settings > Search: "Prefix Header".
5. Under "Apple LLVM 7.0" you will get the *Prefix Header* key.
6. Type file directory. e.g: "$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/ProjectName-Prefix.pch".
7. Clean project: <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
8. Build project: <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

---

[image: Prefix Header Image]

Comment: I cannot find prefix header in build settings.. How can i add .pch in my project?

Comment: Updated the answer with an image. :)

Comment: Thank you! Why to change something that works perfectly?

Comment: @emotality what is the difference between YourProjectName and YourProject, and also when you create the .pch file should I check any checkbox for targets?

Comment: Well it depends on your project folder name and the name you gave it for the pch file. YourFolder/YourPch.pch. And I think the target should be your project/app? @LaurStefan

Comment: XCode 7 does not provide the "Prefix Header" option.

Comment: Yes it does, under "Apple LLVM 7.0 Language" in Build Settings. Just make sure you are viewing All and not Basic, top left corner (blue buttons). (:

Comment: doesn't appear to be a preprocessing key for xcode 8.0

Answer (score 9):

Rob Napier's answer at [Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6) is worth reading. He points out that a PCH file is probably not a good idea, and suggests explicitly including .h files into modules that need them.

Comment: while Rob's answer is indeed worth reading, you might also include in your answer that the comments below the answer debate most of what he said. Rob's reputation plays big part of the deal. But one could agree that the answer is subjective, and represents Rob's personal choice not to have a .pch file in his projects.

Answer (score 6):

I've found out that with Xcode 6. You need to manually create the PCH File.

File -> New -> File -> iOS -> C and C++ -> PCH File.

Comment: in the build setting under prefix.header you just need to type your .pch file name

Answer (score 2):

There is a minor error in the answer provided above.Please note that in the build setting under prefix.header you just need to type your .pch file name –

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue was getting ,no input file error

I fixed by Removing .pch file from project and adding again this work for me.hope this help someone.