# Cant find LLVM6.0 in build settings to add .pch prefix header

Tags: ios, xcode6.3, pch

I created a new project using Xcode 6.3.1 and I want to manual add a 'pch' file to my project. I was looking at questions online [PCH File in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305211/pch-file-in-xcode-6) but the selected answer says to go to LLVM6.0 but that does not exist in build settings anymore. Where can i find it to add the .pch?

Comment: You could always create a project with a `.pch` added automatically, then look for where it's used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a prefix header (pch) file you'll have to do the following:

1. Go to (or use <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) File > New > File > Other (in iOS or OSX).
2. Select PCH File.
3. Give it a name and store it somewhere in your project.
4. Go to your project's target > Build Settings.
5. Search for `prefix header`.
6. Under `Apple LLVM 6.1 - Language` you will find the `Prefix Header` key.
7. Add the path to your pch file like so: `$(PROJECT_NAME)/myPrefixHeaderFile.pch`.
8. Clean your project (<kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and build (<kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

Below is a screenshot showing where to find it in `Build Settings`:
[image: Prefix Header (PCH) File]

Answer (score 1):

Search for prefix header -
Under Apple LLVM 6.1 - Language
Set **Precompile Prefix Header** to **Yes**
and then set Path of your .pch file in **Prefix Header**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0wdk.png