# I want to add pch file to my osx application project but thers is no prefix header field in build settings

Tags: xcode, macos, pch

I have followed some tutorial to create a pch file and add it to my project, but there is no way for me to set its path in build settings

Below is the screen shot of my Xcode

http://static.puvsa.org/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-30%20at%208.09.21%20AM.png

http://static.puvsa.org/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-30%20at%208.16.45%20AM.png

I can find Prefix header field in my iOS apps. But in this new created osx application, I can't find it, can any one tell me how to add it?

Comment: I made a mistake, select "All" will show it……

Comment: See the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305211/pch-file-in-xcode-6.

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode 6, you need to add `pch` file by yourself.

[image]

Comment: I have already added it, but there is no way to set it in build settings~

Comment: [This link may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305211/pch-file-in-xcode-6)