# Not able to add .pch file in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I was trying to add a .pch file in my Xcode project with iOS SDK 8.3, but was getting an error:

> no such file or directory: '/Users/classic/Downloads/appname/appname/appname-Prefix.pch'

I was following this link:
[PCH File in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305211/pch-file-in-xcode-6)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below Code :

**GoTo > Project > Build Settings > Apple LLVM 6.1 Language** then Set 
Precompile prefix header : Yes
Prefix Header : Paste Your File name here (eg Sample-Prefix.pch) . As given in below image .
[image: Image Description]
**Note:** *Select Combined in level to easy understand . As showing in below* image :[image: Image description]