# Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView' in iOS Swift Project

Tags: swift, uiview, ios9, mbprogresshud, bridging-header

I have a `swift` project which I'm making use of `MBProgressHUD` in through a Bridging header file. The issue I'm having is that `UIView` doesn't appear to be recognised as type and I don't know why.

In my bridging header I have:

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

The errors I get when I try to build are all along the same lines:

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of MBProgressHUD.
```

I have checked the MBProgressHUD file and I can see that it definitely imports the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "CSNotificationView.h"
```

Has anyone else seen a similar issue? If so do you know what the issue is and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of your project to github? This is probably project settings related or a typo somewhere.

Comment: did you install MBProgressHUD via CocoaPods? or downloaded manually?

Comment: I downloaded it manually and included it in the project. I should add that this used to work without any problems before I updated the project for iOS 9 as Xcode suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also come across the same issue and thats what i did to use MBProgressHud with swift 2

1) Specify use_frameworks! in your Podfile to use frameworks.

2) Add #import  in your bridging header, use angle brackets instead of double quotes e.g -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>
```

3) in your swift file also import MBProgressHUD e.g.

```
import UIKit
import MBProgressHUD
```

Now you can use MBProgressHud like -

```
MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the original error has gone away however I now see an error `'MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h' file not found` which shows up on the import for MBProgressHUD in the bridging header file. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please use angle brackets while importing in bridging header file e.g #import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>

Comment: Yes I am using angle brackets in the header file (I precisely followed your steps). I'm still not sure why I get the file not found error though. Have you ever come across this issue before?

Comment: Hey make sure you are not creating two bridging header file.. i know it sounds silly but that can be a case..

Answer (score 3):

Remove your existing `bridging header` file and add a new one.

Make sure you are adding your bridging header path in `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER` under the target section instead of the project section.

Comment: Thanks - Just tried your suggestion for deleting and re-adding the file, however I still seem to get the same error message. I also double checked that the filepath exists and the bridging header is actually in the same place (which it is).

Answer (score 1):

If you include the `MBProgressHUD` library with `CocoaPods` try to include a line similar to this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

in 
`BridgeHeader.h` and in Objective-C Bridging Header key in Build Settings choose the header. 
For test if the library is correctly added I try to show a progress with this instruction in the `ViewController`:

```
MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true);
```

I tried it in a new project and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried this too, however it didn't help. I've updated my question slightly to reflect it.

Comment: As described in my modified answer, check if it help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try adding a precompiled prefix header file (.pch) to your project. You'll find it under File/New/Other, there add the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`clause, and then in the target's build settings, under Apple LLVM 7.0 - Language, set the Precompile Prefix Header flag to yes and add the .pch file like this "YourProjectName/YourProject-Prefix.pch".

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305211/pch-file-in-xcode-6).