# How to create AppDelegate shared Instance in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, appdelegate

How to create `sharedInstance` of `AppDelegate` and use in my Application anywhere.

Comment: use this macro #define myappDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

Comment: Do you need in objective C or swift?

Comment: AppDelegate *appdelegate =((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

Comment: AppDelegate is already shared throughout the app, you can use it's instance like [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: Did you even search for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use like this:

In the AppDelegate.h

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate{
    return (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

Comment: How to deal with the info that appears on the return line? 
_[UIApplication delegate] must be used from main thread only._

Answer (score 2):

declare the statement in Constants.h

```
#define myappDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

and you can use `myappDelegate` any where in the app if you declare the Constants.h in .pch file

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305211/pch-file-in-xcode-6) for PCH for Xcode 6

Answer (score 1):

Use this in every ViewControllers

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Or you can create a method in ViewController subclass & use it in every ViewControllers.

```
-(AppDelegate*) app
{
   return (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

In a subclass of UIViewController -- then make that the base-class of all of your view controllers.

Then, [self app] works, and you don't have to keep a reference.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like bellow

**In Objective C** : you can add following line in your .pch file and user where ever you want

```
#define myAppDelegate (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

and use like `myAppDelegate.someVariable or [myAppDelegate somemethod]`

**In Swift**

Swift >= 1.2 (Introduced with Xcode 6.3)

```
let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let aVariable = myAppDelegate.someVariable
```

Swift < 1.2

```
let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let aVariable = myAppDelegate.someVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)appDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers use UIApplication.shared.delegate, but you need to write always 'as! AppDelegate', so a Swift more clean code:

```swift
// AppDelegate.swift

static var shared = AppDelegate() // Declare a static variable as an instance of AppDelegate

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Singleton
    AppDelegate.shared = self // set the value of "shared" to the current instance

    return true
}
```

**Usage**

```
AppDelegate.shared
```

Answer (score -3):

Any ViewController it is working this appDelegate including Xcode 8 also

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```