# .pch replacement to put constant file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

ProjectName-Prefix.pch is Missing in Xcode 6.

We can create .h file and use #define to create constants and then include this  file to prefix file of our project before Xcode 6.

Sample constant.h file

```
 #define OK @"OK"
```

Go to View Controller include file in header  #import "Constants.h" 
OR **Define in pch file ,so that all View controllers** can access the file

In viewDidLoad

```
NSLog(@"%@",OK);
```

**My question is**

where to include my constant.h file so can be access the file from all view controllers like we did using .pch file?

EDIT:
**My question is replacement of .pch file ? As if apple remove it from Xcode their must be some alternate to achieve this goal without adding .pch and include in every single file to be used**

Comment: You can add .pch file, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/26126037/5362916

Comment: I think your question has a pretty good answer here
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 1):

You answered your question yourself. Here

`We can create .h file and use #define to create constants and then include this file to prefix file of our project before Xcode 6.`

You include the Common.h file inside the `pch` file. And you dont have to `#import` anything, as PCH file is available in all classes, and any import inside the PCH file is also available in all classes. Hence PCH files are termed as **Pre-Compiled Header** files.

Comment: my question is replacement of .pch file ?
As if apple remove it from Xcode their must be some alternate to achieve this goal without adding .pch and include in every single file to be used

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a `pch` file in Build Settings->Prefix Header. Type in the path to the pch file or a .h file relative to the xcodeproj file.

Answer (score -1):

Yes You can create header file for Xcode. I am sure pch is best way to used whole application. You can import constant file on pch and used in whole application.

Comment: The question is that .pch is missing so he needs to figure out his way out of it.