# clang: error: no such file or directory: .pch

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m trying to compile a project in xcode and facing below error

> **clang: error: no such file or directory:** '/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PartySlots-fvyybtfnscszlhagtcwimkjnmdjx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/PartySlots-Prefix-fdmipifdnmujjacmntzgkdilgdnc/PartySlots-Prefix.pch'

Comment: Show us relevant code so that SO community can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PCH File in Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305211/pch-file-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 6):

Did you move your folder/files after making the project? It's because Xcode can't find the prefix header for some reason. It can be easily fixed by relocating it.

Change the **Precompile Prefix Header** to **Yes** and **Prefix Header** to where the .pch file is located in your folder.

Refer the image.

[image]

Comment: Xcode seems to be stricter about how these paths are defined. Older Xcode versions would accept something like this: /MyApp/SupportingFiles/My.pch where now it needs $(SRCROOT)/MyApp/SupportingFiles.pch