# Compile in Xcode Prefix.pch not found

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am a beginner in react-native. I tried to compile the apps, ran the `pod install` (because I used cocoapods I have to do this, I guess), and opened the generated `xcworkspace`. After I hit the compile button, this error show up

```
Showing All Messages
No such file or directory: '/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project name>-bvczmgvzvgwjpyfsmvczxliopbfo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/7446126693023229553/Prefix.pch'
```

The xcconfig file I used already had GCC_PREFIX_HEADER and targeted on correct file. It stated like this

`GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = $(SRCROOT)/ExportedProject/Classes/Prefix.pch;`

I checked my project's configurations using target "Release" and it pointed to the correct xcconfig file.

I searched around and found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164807/clang-error-no-such-file-or-directory-pch). I checked on my **Build Settings > Apple Clang - Language - Prefix Header**, and it also targeted on the correct path and has the `Precompile Prefix Header` filled with "Yes".

I tried to use `pod-deintegrate`; reimport the project; deleted the project and use `react-native upgrade`, but nothing works.