# RestKit Swift Error "Value of type 'RKObjectManager' has no member 'managedObjectStore'"

Tags: swift, restkit, restkit-0.26.x

I have installed RestKit 0.26 using cocoapods and importing RestKit in Bridging-Header as following :

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <RestKit/CoreData.h>
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
```

In AppDelegate.swift Im trying to initialise RestKit but facing this error "Value of type 'RKObjectManager' has no member 'managedObjectStore'" on following code line

```
self.rkManagedObjectStore = RKManagedObjectStore(managedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel)
self.rkObjectManager.managedObjectStore = self.rkManagedObjectStore
```

Its more likely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819652/property-managedobjectstore-not-found-on-object-of-type-rkobjectmanager) existing error but in Swift

Any helping pointer?
Thanks,